# React Profile-view isn’t updating, deleting or change favMovies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

[movieAPI](https://github.com/WinstonMuijs/MovieAPI)

[React client-view with components](https://github.com/WinstonMuijs/artHouseMovie-client)

Hi there, the following is the problem. I build a profile-view in react. I get the User info from my API, but i can’t register, delete, update or change the the info. I think the problem lies in the points in react in comb with the API, but i’m not sure.

Is there someone that can review the code or make suggestions on what is wrong?

The code of the profile-view is:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// Import React Bootstrap Components
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";


export class ProfileView extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: null,
      password: null,
      email: null,
      birthday: null,
      favoriteMovies: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    this.getUser(accessToken);
  }

  removeFavorite = (e, movie) => {
    const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log(this.props);
    axios
      .delete(
        `https://arthousemovies.herokuapp.com/users/${user}/movies/${movie._id}`,
        { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        alert("Movie was removed from favorites.");
        this.componentDidMount();
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  onLoggedOut() {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    this.setState({
      user: null,
    });
    window.open("/", "_self");
  }

  getUser = (token) => {
    const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    axios
      .get(`https://arthousemovie.herokuapp.com/users/${user}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          name: response.data.name,
          password: response.data.password,
          email: response.data.email,
          birthday: response.data.birthday,
          favoriteMovies: response.data.favoriteMovies,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  editUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    console.log(user);
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    axios
      .put(
        `https://arthousemovie.herokuapp.com/users/${user}`,
        {
          name: this.state.name,
          password: this.state.password,
          email: this.state.email,
          birthday: this.state.birthday,
        },
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          name: response.data.name,
          password: response.data.password,
          email: response.data.email,
          birthday: response.data.birthday,
        });

        localStorage.setItem("user", this.state.name);
        const data = response.data;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this.state.name);
        alert("Profile is updated!");
        window.open(`/users/${user}`, "_self");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  // Deregister
  onDeleteUser() {
    const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    axios
      .delete(`https://arthousemovie.herokuapp.com/users/${user}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        alert("Profile has been deleted!");
        localStorage.removeItem("user");
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        window.open(`/`, "_self");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  // Set user values
  setUsername(value) {
    this.setState({
      name: value,
    });
    this.name = value;
  }

  setPassword(value) {
    this.setState({
      password: value,
    });
    this.password = value;
  }

  setEmail(value) {
    this.setState({
      email: value,
    });
    this.email = value;
  }

  setBirthday(value) {
    this.setState({
      birthday: value,
    });
    this.birthday = value;
  }

  render() {
    const { favoriteMovies, name, email, birthday} = this.state;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Card className="user-profile">
              <Card.Header>User Profile</Card.Header>
              <Card.Body>
                <div>
                  <p>Name: {name}</p>
                  <p>Email: {email}</p>
                  <p>Birthday: {birthday}</p>
                </div>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <Card className="update-inputs">
              <Card.Header>Update Profile</Card.Header>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Text>
                  <Form
                    className="update-form"
                    onSubmit={(e) =>
                      this.editUser(
                        e,
                        this.name,
                        this.password,
                        this.email,
                        this.birthday
                      )
                    }
                  >
                    <Form.Group>
                      <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        placeholder="New Username"
                        onChange={(e) => this.setUsername(e.target.value)}
                        required
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group>
                      <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="New Password"
                        onChange={(e) => this.setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        required
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group>
                      <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        placeholder="New Email"
                        onChange={(e) => this.setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        required
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group>
                      <Form.Label>Birthday</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control
                        type="date"
                        name="birthday"
                        onChange={(e) => this.setBirthday(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group>
                      <Button
                        variant="warning"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={() => this.editUser()}
                      >
                        Update User
                      </Button>
                      <Button
                        className="delete-button"
                        variant="danger"
                        onClick={() => this.onDeleteUser()}
                      >
                        Delete User
                      </Button>
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Form>
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row></Row>
        <Card className="favmov-inputs">
          <Card.Body>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={12}>
                <h4>Favorite Movies</h4>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              {favoriteMovies.map((imageURL,movie, title, _id) => {
                return (
                <Row>
                  <Col key={_id} className="fav-movie">
                    <Card>
                      <Link to={`/movies/${movie._id}`}>
                        <Card.Img src={imageURL} alt={title} />
                        <Card.Title>{title}</Card.Title>
                      </Link>
                        <Button
                            className="remove"
                            variant="secondary"
                            onClick={() => this.removeFavorite(e, movie)}
                        >
                        Remove from the list
                        </Button>
                    </Card>
                  </Col>
                 </Row>
                );
              })}
            </Row>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does your code even run? Do you see any info in the network tab?

Comment: I get a CORS warning that it didn't the access control. So I have to place an acces control header in the view. Warning is: Warning'https://arthousmovie.herokuapp.com/users' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}

Comment: The Header part I don't really understand because with the login I didn't use a header, so I thought I could also use the same sort of code for register.

Comment: You always send and receiver headers with every request

Comment: This is when I update  :profile-view.jsx:80 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault').  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)arthousemovie.herokuapp.com/users/Winston:1

Comment: You form component doesn't pass an event to the `onSubmit` handler

Comment: I'm just starting React so this is for study purpose only. When I submit at this point a get the alert in .catch f the handleSubmit. So I can't reach the users and don't get a response when updating. any suggestions in the code?